# PowerShell: set value in CSV column if output matches string

Tags: powershell

First of all, this is my first Stack Overflow post so I apologize if this has been answered somewhere else and I couldn't find it, but here's what I'm trying to figure out.

I'm looping through a CSV list of usernames, getting the Office 365 license status for each user, and I want to write a string back to the CSV for that user based on the license status.  So for example, the CSV looks like this:

```
Username     License1     License2
user1
user2
user3
```

And here's the code:

```
$users = Import-Csv .\users.csv

foreach ($user in $users) {

$licenses = (Get-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName $_.Username).Licenses.AccountSkuId

    if ($licenses -match "XYZ") {
        $_License1 = "XYZ" | Export-Csv .\users.csv -NoTypeInformation
    }
}
```

So if the first two users have the "XYZ" license then the CSV would be updated to look like this:

```
Username     License1     License2
user1        XYZ
user2        XYZ
user3
```

It's not working, and I'm sure the problem has to do with how I'm trying to export the data back to the original CSV, but I don't know how to do it the right way.  Any help is greatly appreciated, and if there is a better way to do this I'm all ears.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$users = Import-Csv .\users.csv

foreach ($user in $users) {
    $licenses = (Get-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName $_.Username).Licenses.AccountSkuId

    if ($licenses -match "XYZ") {
        $user.License1 = "XYZ"
    }
}

$users | Export-Csv .\users.csv -NoTypeInformation
```